# how to make scanner object as static

Tags: java, object, static, global-variables, java.util.scanner

how can i refer to Scanner object which is defined globally from a static method(say main() ).. That is, how to make Scanner object as static.

Program (# for reference to my problem) :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class spidy {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);             /*DECLARING SCANNER OBJECT OUTSIDE MAIN METHOD i.e Static method */


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int n = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Error: 
non static variable input cannot be referenced from the static content

Comment: declare `static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: Note that an _object_ is not _static_. A _variable_ is (or a method or a class).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had faced a similar doubt while solving a problem on Static Initializer Block. And there is a simple solution to it.

Write as:

```
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Instead of :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 9):

If I understand your question, then you could change this

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

to (visible to all other classes - you said *global*)

```
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

or (visible to the current class - any other static method (`main()` in your case) )

```
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `static` keyword before `Scanner` class.

Example:

```
static Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
```

By using the scan object we refer anywhere in the code